# Google Maps V3 InfoWindow ignores latLng position

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, infowindow

My map has no markers. In response to a click on the map, it pops up an infowindow with Lat/long shown in decimal to 5 dp and in Degrees minutes seconds. An open window is always closed prior to responding to a new click. The position is specified by position: latLng, but the infowindow is ALWAYS at the top left. I've spent days on this, and I feel I'm missing something. Code snippet below.  Any ideas?

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (event) {
    var lat = event.latLng.lat(),
        lng = event.latLng.lng(),
        latLng = event.latLng,
        strHtml;
    //
    // strHtml build code omitted but succesfully uses lat and lng to produce
    // e.g. Latitude : 51.72229 N (51° 43' 20'' N)
    //      Longitude : 1.45827 E (1° 27' 30'' E)
    //
    // If an infowindow is open, then close it
    if (openedInfoWindow != null) openedInfoWindow.close();
    // latLng monitored to check it is there before use in infowindow
    alert(latLng); // returns correct values which position then ignores!
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        position: latLng, 
        content: strHtml,
        maxWidth: 420
    });
    // Open infoWindow
    infoWindow.open(map,this);
    // Remember the opened window
    openedInfoWindow = infoWindow;
    // Close it if X box clicked
    google.maps.event.addListener(infoWindow, 'closeclick', function() {
    openedInfoWindow = null; 
    });    
});
```

Comment: Removing 2nd argument worked perfectly. Many thanks Dr Molle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 2nd (optional)argument of `infoWindow.open()` is expected to be an `MVCObject` that exposes a position-property.

the `this` argument in the callback refers to a `google.maps.Map`-Instance(map), which is an `MVCObject`, but doesn't have a `position`-property.

Remove the 2nd argument from `infoWindow.open(map,this);` .

Answer (score 5):

You have several problems with this code.  The second parameter of the infowindow's `open` method has to be an `MVCObject`  in the Core API only the `Marker` class can be used as an anchor.  You should not need to set the infowindow variable to null and create a new infowindow object each time.  You only need a single infowindow and then change its content and position.  This way there is only one infowindow shown at a time.

Here is a fiddle of a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/bryan_weaver/z3Cdg/

relevant code:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (evt) {
       var content = "<div class='infowindow'>";
       content += "Latitude: " + evt.latLng.lat() + "<br/>";
       content += "Longitude: " + evt.latLng.lng() + "</div>";
       HandleInfoWindow(evt.latLng, content);
});

function HandleInfoWindow(latLng, content) {
    infoWindow.setContent(content);
    infoWindow.setPosition(latLng);
    infoWindow.open(map);
}
```

Comment: Bryan - A very useful suggestion which I'll learn from. I'll adapt my code too.